# How to configure asp to render attributes in defined order

Tags: asp.net, webforms

In asp if we set

```
<button class="classA" id="myId"/>
```

it will render

```
<button id="ctl00_myId" class="classA"/>
```

Some times id can be bery long like `ctl_00_placeholder1_ctl01_placeholder2....myId`
and when we look on node tree in devtools in browsers it is more convenient to have class first.

[image]

Is there any way to configure asp to render server control's attributes in order that we define?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to force the attributes to render in order but if you set your client id mode to static the id won't append all the add values to the id.

```
<%@ Page ClientIDMode="Static" %>
```

This will make it easier to read in browser dev tools.

Comment: yeah I know about this, but this will make id static and if we have many partials on page and all have static id, they may conflict.